# Google plus page indexing issue

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, search-results, google-plus

I have a question related to my company's G+ page. I had created a page around one year ago but it's not yet indexed on Google. When I search for my company's name I don't see its G+ page in SERPs. The visibility of the page is already set to public.

Could anyone help me in this?

Comment: Is your Google+ page your company's main site or a social media extension of your company's main site? If the latter, is it frequently updated with good content and linked to from your main site? Are you using ORIGINAL pictures on G+ and videos on its associated YouTube channel as part of your content? Finally, do you have legitimate followers (as opposed to store-bought ones)?

Comment: In addition to everything else, make sure you have a vanity URL, so that your G+ page is not a string of seemingly random numbers and letters. If not, be sure to reserve it: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Google plus profile check if the setting **Help others discover my profile in search results** is turned off, is so switch it on.

Check [this page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1151728?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) for more info on how to find it. Take note of the following also:

> If your organization has restricted content sharing, this option may not be available.

Also check *Allow access outside your organization’s domain* and your *privacy content* in this [privacy settings page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3379754?hl=en)

You can also check [organisational settings using this instructions](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4524919?hl=en)

**Get indexed**

To make sure you get indexed after checking your profile settings do:

- Link your G+ profile from other social media profiles or websites.
- Join G+ communities or groups
- Create circles and add friends
- Follow other organisations, share their content
- Post some original and curated content yourself

**Check if you are indexed**

Go to google and check if you are indexed, just google:

*Company or profile name google plus*

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Post some original and curated content yourself" this approach worked for us :)